# Profiling running ASP.NET application in production

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to profile a web application running on IIS in a Production environment (.Net framework 4.0, WebForms, SQLServer, Windows 2008 server) .
Several pages are repeatedly slow in Production, but we are unable to reproduce in Development.
We cannot install any IDE or similar tool in the Production environment.
Does anyone know of a DLL or a stand-alone exe that we could easily drop into the server, run for about an hour, and then quickly and easily remove?.... we are seeking one important aspect to profiling:
-->    what is the amount of time spent for each CSharp method to run.  <--

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [SO] doesn't do recommendations, but there are various tools out there. The best known (at the time of writing) is probably [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/), but for any detail you'll need to add information gathering inside the application.

Comment: Another good .NET profiler tool is dotTrace by Jetbrains. It allows local and remote profiling. They have a free 10 day trial: https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://github.com/jitbit/cpu-analyzer command-line tool for profiling cpu load in production.

We forked this from the original Sam Saffron's cpu profiler, which is kinda abandoned now.

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of this project.

Answer (score 0):

[Perfview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) is the one of the best tool for this purpose, have used to find numerous production issues.

You can narrow down the issue using multiple approach, it can tell from network level to IIS to asp.net to your C# methods.It uses ETW events emitted by IiS,Asp.net and CLR to do this.

- https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial/PerfView-Tutorial-7-Using-the-Event-Viewer-in-ASPNET-Scenarios

  - https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial
  - using the [ThreadTime](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1035965/Understanding-the-Thread-Time-view-in-PerfView) view you can narrow down to a particular method

Perfview  always collect system wide data  and you can also set a circular buffer .But best way to collect data is when the issue starts happening, You go to the server in question and start perfview trace and reproduce the issue.Then you can analyze this data later to find the performance bottleneck.